# proc sql aggregate

Tags: sql, sas, aggregate, proc

I have written some code:

```
proc sql;
    create table single_model_summary_na(label = "&label") as
    select exposure_index, gen, max(survival_time) as max_st, max(event_prob) as max_ep
    from single_model_scored
    group by exposure_index, gen
    having exposure_index = 0
;
quit;
```

which appears to be running smoothly, until I test the other three exposure indices I have - the aggregated event_prob is identical for all four cases, although I know from other analyses that this isn't true.  Could anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?

single_model_scored is a large dataset that contains the variables I have used along with several others.

The eventual result I would be hoping for (by joining in the proc sql or otherwise) would be along the lines of

```
exposure_index  gen max_st max_ep
0               0   36     .01
0               1   36     .015
1               0   36     .02
1               1   36     .025
```

and etc.

The results I am actually getting are:

```
exposure_index  gen max_st max_ep
    0               0   36     .039329674
    0               1   36     .0685513975
    1               0   36     .039329674
    1               1   36     .0685513975
```

Comment: What do you mean by "aggregated `event_prob`"?  Your query is only pulling the maximum.

Comment: use a `where`  clause instead of `having` like this : `where exposure_index = 0`

Comment: Hi - I tried the 'where' approach and it produces exactly the same results.  I wish to pull the maximum of event_prob only when it is true that exposure_index = 0.

Comment: @Zephyris . . . I think you should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: can you please include the results you get with your query as well?

Comment: how can you get rows for `exposure_index = 1` when you are filtering for `exposure_index = 0`?

Comment: I was testing the code by amending the exposure_index before running it for each of my 4 cases - that is when I noticed that I was producing identical results, regardless of the exposure_index.

Comment: that suggests to me that you have something wrong in the table `single_model_scored`

Comment: Yes - I think you might be right - I'm just investigating it now.  Thanks for looking, anyway - much appreciated!